# Would providing `EntityManagerFactory` solve `Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName xyz`

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

This is the (bottom) error from the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:477)
...
```

The code is as follows (inspired by a `@BalusC`'s example I found on SO today):

```
@Stateless
public class GradService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Grad> listAll() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Grad g", Grad.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

As reference, this is my persistence.xml (webmodule-root:Configuration files:<del>WEB-INF</del>META-INF:persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MojaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/ekstraResource</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I just read that the `context` is actually info contained in the `persistence.xml` from which the `Persistencemanager` is created (so I guess there's no need to declare and initiate it in the file itself. However, I still need clarification on what's wrong with my `persistence.xml` then?

Comment: @BalusC Just thought you might be interested in taking a look into this as this is actually based on an example of yours (not sure if it also used Hibernated but anyway...).

Comment: Have you tried using `@PersistenceContext(unitName="MojaPU")`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Yes, but still no luck.

Comment: @developer10 did you ever find the fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you placed your persistence.xml file in wrong location. It should by located in /META-INF/ folder and not in WEB-INF.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake when composing the post. It's in `META-INF` folder indeed.